# how to add or modify the date in mongo db pipeline through node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an api in nodejs, which performs mongodb aggregation, in that pipeline the date values will add through request params with the help of an api, aggregation is working fine. but these date values are not getting evaluated.

my nodejs aggregate pipeline:

```
const result = await db.collection.aggregate(
  {
    "$match": {
      "TaskCompletedDate": { "$gte": "new Date(`${req.query.startDate}`)", "$lt":"new Date(`${req.query.endDate}`)" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id":{
        "ProductTypeCode":"$ProductTypeCode"
      },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id":0,
      "concat":{ "$concat": [{ "$toString": "$count" }, "$_id.ProductTypeCode"] }
    }
  }
]).toArray();
```

Passing startDate and endDate through API like this:
http://localhost:3000/stored_procedure/HRC_getTaskCompletedCountPerProduct?startDate="2022-01-12T00:00:00.0Z"&endDate="2022-01-23T00:00:00.0Z"

The aggregation is working fine. But I am not able to see output when I am passing dates like mentioned above. Can anyone please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  $match: {
    "TaskCompletedDate":  {
      $gte: req.query.startDate,
      $lte: req.query.endDate
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
"new Date(`${req.query.startDate}`)"
```

is evaluated as a literal string. You cannot use JavaScript's backticks for string substitution inside double-quotes.

Try using

```
[
 {
    "$match": {
      "TaskCompletedDate": { "$gte": new Date(`${req.query.startDate}`), "$lt": new Date(`${req.query.endDate}`) }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id":{
        "ProductTypeCode":"$ProductTypeCode"
      },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id":0,
      "concat":{ "$concat": [{ "$toString": "$count" }, "$_id.ProductTypeCode"] }
    }
  }
]
```

If the dates are stored as strings (not actual date objects) in Mongo,
then use:

```
new Date(`${req.query.startDate}`).toISOString()
```

Comment: I am using toISOString() but same I am not able to see response

Comment: If dates are stored as date objects then you need to pass an actual date object in your aggregation pipe. Strings won't work.

Comment: dates are stored as strings.

Comment: There is an another API to stores these aggregations using POST API. SO I am not getting error "new Date(`${req.query.startDate}`)" when I push like this. How to push correctly without any error